# Remove specific words string (both prefix and postfix) from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace, prefix

I want to keep the latest rows with the same ID and also the rows that match certain column values.

```
Sample Input:
```

```
ID                  Address
1                   PALLABI- F #1st Floor, SEC #10, Pallabi, MIRPUR
2                   H#22(2nd floor),Extended Rupnagar Area, Pallabi Mirpur, Dhaka.
3                   Uttar khan-F #3rd floor, Kuripara, Dhaka
4                   F-1,H-43,Chalabon,D.khan, Uttarkhan
```

> PREFIX

*ID 1* has a word **PALLABI-**  i want to remove that part. Similar goes for *ID 3* where
**Uttar khan-** should be removed. After removal **Uttar khan** or **PALLABI** part should add to the postfix of the string only if the prefix doesn't contain any of these words.

> POSTFIX

Another part is to remove **Dhaka** at the end of the string.

```
Output:
```

```
ID                  Address
1                   F #1st Floor, SEC #10, Pallabi, MIRPUR
2                   H#22(2nd floor),Extended Rupnagar Area, Pallabi Mirpur
3                   F #3rd floor, Kuripara, Uttar khan
4                   F-1,H-43,Chalabon,D.khan, Uttarkhan
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to the column;

```
def my_function(string): 
    # if your word is the first in the string
    if 'your_word' == string.split()[0]:
        # replace it with your requirement (it can be nothing (''))
        string = string.replace('what/you/need/to/replace', 'replacement') 

    return string

df['column'] = df['column'].apply(my_function)
```

Comment: No, this will remove both words. I want to remove specific words at the beginning of the string. If the same word appears at the end of the word then i won't remove it. If i follow your instruction, the output of the ID 1 will be:   F #1st Floor, SEC #10,  MIRPUR

Comment: I was simply exposing the technique, not the logic. I've updated my answer.